# Finding in-between 2 consecutive numbers (regEx)

Tags: regex

I have bee trying to create a exam paper parser. I am struggling to make a regular expression for capturing the question in-between 2 consecutive numbers.
Here is a sample of the paper:

```
21 (a) (i) Protons Neutrons Electrons
29 Si 14
1
22 (a) (i) Oxidised
```

I would like to capture the `21` and `(a) (i) Protons Neutrons Electrons 29 Si 14 16 14 1` in this example.

Here is my attempt https://regex101.com/r/dlESTV/3 I am finding this very difficult, because the expression will capture everything in-between the 21 and 29 (instead of 22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(\d+) (.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+ +\([a-z]+\)).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlESTV/4).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- - a space (you may add `+` after the space, but it is only necessary if you need to make sure there is a `(` after it)
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+ +\([a-z]+\)).*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\d+ +\([a-z]+\)).*)*` - zero or more lines that do not start with

    - `\d+` - one or more digits
    - `+` - one or more spaces
    - `\([a-z]+\)` - a `(`, then one or more lowercase ASCII letters, then `)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a legend!